# Is it feasible to use this method to determine whether numerical solutions to linear equations converge?

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization

I need to solve a linear equation Ax = b. I am able to use Gauss-Seidel iteration and Jacobian iteration

However, these two iterative methods need to determine whether they converge, otherwise they will waste time.

I found the judgment methods on wiki, but they are quite complicated.
(1:A is symmetric positive-definite, 2: A is strictly or irreducibly diagonally dominant. 3:Calculate spectral radius)

I want to be able to quickly and easily determine if an equation is divergent.
So I came up with this:

**if err^i > err^i-1 then judged as diverging**
err = A * x^i - b; i is the number of iterations.

My idea is: if the error of this iteration is larger than the error of the previous time, it will be judged as divergence.

I'm not very good at math, so I'd like to ask everyone if this method is feasible.Thx

Comment: Interesting question, but it's off topic here since it isn't a specific programming problem; try math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @RobertDodier  Sorry, because this problem was encountered when I was programming, so I posted it to this forum. As for why I didn’t post the code, it’s because I hope this question won’t be limited to a certain programming language.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I'm just saying that you'll find a better audience for this question in another forum. People who answer questions here are, for the most part, not really adept with the mathematical concepts behind the code. In any event, you will find more people who can speak to the math stuff elsewhere. I'm just trying to help you help yourself by finding the appropriate forum.